# fbsetbg gives error whenever i startx

Tags: linux, desktop, desktop-customization

Whenever I startx, I get this error message from fbsetbg.

```
fbsetbg: Something went wrong while setting the wallpaper. Run 'display -geometry 1280x1024+0+0 -wn xterm to find out what.
```

This confuses me because my wallpaper is actually displayed after this message just fine.

Here is my .xinitrc which uses fbsetbg:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
fbsetbg ~/pics/peace.jpg
/usr/bin/xmonad
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of 'display -geometry ...' too?

Comment: Please post anything interesting out of your /var/log/Xlog.0.log file.

Comment: just to state the obvious: did you "run 'display -geometry 1280x1024+0+0 -wn xterm to find out what."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fbsetbg is a wrapper program for trying to set your background.  It tries to do what you mean, not what you say. You're supposed to use one of -fctaFCTA with a file.  How about: `fbsetbg -f ~/pics/peace.jpg`

Try [man fbsetbg](http://linuxreviews.org/man/fbsetbg/)

Also, what's your DISPLAY environment variable set to?